# Permission denied when try any command in magento 2.1

Tags: product, css, magento-2.1.3, command-line, file-permissions

[image]

When I try to set permissions to folder and files using command like

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                    // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                    // 755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

after using this command my site not working properly and permission denied error when try any command

Comment: You need to run the above commands with sudo permission ... e.g) `sudo chmod 777 ./app/etc`

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 app/etc/

Comment: I try this command it shows "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to have root privileges in order to give permission, If you are using  amazon ec2 try:- sudo su - to switch to root and then try to give permission